# Why setting HttpSession is giving me a blank page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpsession

Here's the part of the code:

```
if (results.get(0).equals(username) && results.get(1).equals(password)) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if(session != null) {
        session.setAttribute("lg_username", results.get(2));
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/Olapp/index.jsp");
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("/Olapp/wrongPassword.jsp");
}
```

When I log in, I never get redirected back to the index.jsp, because the Servlet gets stuck in the HttpSession part (If I remove it, it redirects instantly). Why that happens?

EDIT:

The same happens when I use RequestDispatcher.

Comment: Use RequestDispatcher instead of sendRedirect()

Comment: The same happens when I use RequestDispatcher.

Comment: What are the lines you removed in order to work it fine? Do you get any exceptions with the current posted code above?

Comment: Bloody hell! I really was that stupid (I had removed the session-related parts). There was an index exception, and that's why it was blank. So that's the answer: Just me being stupid haha.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is JSP page then use session.getSession(false) instead of
>   resuest.getSession(false)